# Infinite Outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi i'm making an app where you can decorate a Christmas tree with baubles i have wrote code to be able to drag it around the view but i run out of baubles how do i make it so i can have lots of baubles to put on the christmas tree. I have tried duplicating one bauble lots of times but then added them all to the code and it doesn't work it drags them all at the same time. If you look in the picture it has the bauble in it but i want it to drag one but one to still be there to put on
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var red_bauble_1: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.wasDragged(_ :)))
        red_bauble_1.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        red_bauble_1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func wasDragged (_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        let red_bauble_1 = gesture.view

        red_bauble_1?.center = CGPoint(x: red_bauble_1!.center.x + translation.x, y: (red_bauble_1?.center.y)! + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm gonna need to see more than a picture of a Christmas Tree to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ive added the code

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python?

Comment: Because i couldn't think of anything else to put and its a popular tag to get more people to see it i will delete it if its a problem

Comment: You can't just pick tags at random in the hope of getting more people to see it...! If anything, that will attract more downvotes due to the irrelevance of the tag.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use a version-specific tag like `swift4` unless you question is specific to Swift version 4. You already have the Swift tag, so I would say get rid of the `swift4` tag.

Comment: @DuncanC - That’s on me. He had Swift 4 in the title, so I removed it from title and added the tag. Now removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding a variable number of ornaments as subviews and want to keep a reference to them, just have an array for them, e.g.

```
var ornaments = [UIView]()  // or, if they're image views, `[UIImageView]()`
```

then you can add your ornaments to that array as you add them to your tree and you have an array to keep track of all of them.

---

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var treeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ornamentToolImageView: UIImageView!

    private var currentOrnament: UIView!

    private var ornaments = [UIView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragOrnamentFromToolbar(_:)))
        ornamentToolImageView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    /// Gesture for dragging ornament from toolbar on to the tree
    ///
    /// This creates new ornament and adds it to view hierarchy as well as to our array of `ornaments`

    @IBAction func dragOrnamentFromToolbar(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gesture.location(in: treeImageView)

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            gesture.view?.isHidden = true                 // temporarily hide toolbar view so it feels like we're dragging it
            let image = UIImage(named: "ornament")!
            currentOrnament = UIImageView(image: image)
            ornaments.append(currentOrnament)
            treeImageView.addSubview(currentOrnament)
            fallthrough

        case .changed:
            currentOrnament.center = location

        case .ended, .cancelled:
            // when done, add new pan gesture for dragging around new ornament

            gesture.view?.isHidden = false                // restore toolbar view
            currentOrnament.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragExistingOrnament(_:)))
            currentOrnament.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
            currentOrnament = nil

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    /// Gesture for dragging existing ornament
    ///
    /// This grabs existing and allows you to drag it around

    @IBAction func dragExistingOrnament(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gesture.location(in: treeImageView)

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            currentOrnament = gesture.view
            fallthrough

        case .changed:
            currentOrnament.center = location

        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: What Rob said. I was going to suggest the same thing but he beat me to it.

Comment: How do i link my outlets to it?

Comment: You don't. Instead of using outlets, use the array to reference your image views.

Comment: Im sorry this is slightly confusing

Comment: How do i write this then? ornaments.addGestureRecogniser(gesture)

Comment: @TechStar - See example in revised answer.